# Issue with storing Instantiated prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(I'm new to Unity and probably jumping the gun a bit here) -

I'm getting myself a bit confused regarding instantiating prefabs. I have a GameObject (gameManager) that instantiates a prefab, and then sets the reference of the instantiated object to my LevelManager (stores a static gameObject)

I call on the reference to the instantiated object using the LevelManager (LevelManager.enemyPrefabInstance) in other scripts (for reasons such as grabbing the animator component). Because it is stored as static, I think every instantiation has shared components. If I instantiate two enemies and kill one at runtime (once dead the gameObject destroys itself), the 2nd looses its components because they've also been destroyed. I know I could change the prefab reference from static to non-static but I am trying to teach myself about static objects and how they work, so that defeats my purpose.

Is there a way to store all instantiated objects as a single static gameobject, so they all keep have their own individual components?

Many thanks in advance

EDIT - I'm being told instances do not share components regardless if they are stored as static or not. The exact error I get when I try and destory a 2nd instantiated clone is:

MissingReferenceException: The object of type "Animator" has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or not destroy the object.

GameManager Script:

```
Void Awake() 

{
   GameObject enemyPrefabInstantiated = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, position, rotation); 
   //instantiate gameObject

   LevelManager.enemyPrefabInstantiated = enemyPrefabInstantiated;
   //Set reference for LevelManager
}
```

LevelManager:

```
public static GameObject enemyPrefabInstantiated; //Stores static GameObject
```

Animator Script:

```
public Animator enemyAnim;

void Start()
{
  enemyAnim = LevelManager.enemyPrefabInstantiated.GetComponent<Animator>();
  //Gets animator component off instantiated prefab
}

void OnDestroy()
{
  Destroy(enemyAnim.gameObject);
  //destroy gameobject
}
```

Comment: Each instance has its own components (not shared), regardless of if the variable holding it is static or not.

Comment: hmm I wonder why all other clones' components are destroyed after one clone gets destroyed? It doesn't make sense..

Comment: There may be some confusion.  If you only spawn 1 instance, the above code is ok.  If you spawn more than 1 instance, you have an issue.  You can only assign 1 reference to the static field in your level manager.  Each additional assignment replaces the previously assigned reference.

Comment: Thats exactly my issue! How can I use the same code for multiple instances?

Comment: Arrays/lists … which is best is down to your code design

Comment: Do you mean to store each instantiation in an array and then access the components of each through a foreach loop?

Comment: Even without replacing references what would you expect from static game object? You instantiated it, assigned it, destroyed it and now are trying to access it again - but all the references (in all three scripts) are pointing to the same game object, which already had Destroy() called on it

Comment: If you have multiple objects that you routinely instantiate and destroy, you might be interested in implementing object pooling (https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling) instead - and it actually lends itself very well to learning about static, too, since you usually need one singular object pool for everyone who accesses it. You can leave out the "hard" bits and just implement a static list and methods like "get free enemy prefab from list" and "return enemy prefab to list"

Comment: So how would you advise accessing the instantiated objects on other scrips without referencing a single gameobject (since that gets destroyed)? (I am relatively new to Unity if that wasn't obvious enough lol)

Comment: Ah ok! I'll look into that, thank you!

Comment: @EwanWithey: Just curious, is this `Animator` script attached to the `Enemy` gameobject, whose reference is held by `LevelManager`'s static variable `enemyPrefabInstantiated`? If yes, why the need for this static variable in the first place. The `Animator` script can access the gameobject to which it is attached to via `this.gameObject` and find itself via `this` instead of  `GetComponent < ... > ( ... )` what has been used in the code to find its own reference.

Comment: `Is there a way to store all instantiated objects as a single static gameobject` no of course not ^^ You could use a static collection like a `List<Animator>` or `HashSet<Animator>` though

Comment: @nIcEcOw the only reason for the static variable is I'm trying to teach myself about statics. It cleans up the code instead of always instantiating an object of the class, that's all. Other than that it's pretty irrelevant to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your reference is:

```
GameObject prefab; //your prefab you want to instantiate

GameObject obj1 =Instantiate(prefab); 
//create your first gameobject
GameObject obj2 =Instantiate(prefab);
//and the second
```

The obj2 variable now only references the instantiated copy of the prefab.